# Google Play Scrapper python showing incorrect app upon using search function

Tags: python, api

I have been using google play scraper since months but now for 2-3 days it started showing wrong results.

The keyword given by me: **last fortress underground**
App name searched on google play:  **State of Survival: Zombie War**

And since it is searching the wrong results, my script is not working as it should.

The code snippet i am using is below:

```
result = search(app_name,
lang="en",  # defaults to 'en'
country="US",  # defaults to 'us'
n_hits=3  # defaults to 30 (= Google's maximum)
)
print(app_name)
print("App name searched on google play: ", result[0]['title'])
```

Here **app_name** is the keyword i am providing it. Lets say **last fortress underground** and the **result[0]['title']** is **State of Survival: Zombie War**

I tried figuring out the problem but couldn't find the fix. My guess is it is scraping the wrong results somehow because it is generating the correct url.